# Why is it enough to show that $\operatorname{vol} (\partial\tilde K) \le 2n \operatorname{vol}(\tilde K)^{(n-1)/n}$ for Theorem $6.1$?

Tags: analysis, inequality, proof-explanation, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

On Pg. $33$ of [these notes](http://library.msri.org/books/Book31/files/ball.pdf) (a), the author says (somewhere in the middle of the page) that it suffices to prove $$\operatorname{vol} (\partial\tilde K) \le 2n \operatorname{vol}(\tilde K)^{(n-1)/n}$$
in order to prove the **symmetric** version of Theorem $6.1$ using Theorem $6.2$. Why is this true?

The author also remarks that $\operatorname{vol}(\tilde K) \le 2^n$, if $\tilde K$ is such that its maximal volume ellipsoid is $B^n_2$. Why is this true? This is also used later in the proof of Theorem $6.2$.

Reference (b) has some details but I could not find anything that answers my question.

---

For reference:

> **Symmetric case of Theorem $6.1$:**
> Let $K$ be a convex body and $Q$ a cube in $\mathbb R^n$. Then, there is an affine image of $K$ whose volume is the same as that of $Q$ and whose surface area is no larger than that of $Q$.

> **Theorem $6.2$:**
> Among symmetric convex bodies the cube has the largest volume ratio.

where the volume ratio $\operatorname{vr}(K)$ for convex bodies is defined as
$$\operatorname{vr}(K) = \frac{\operatorname{vol}(K)}{\operatorname{vol}(\mathcal E)}$$
where $\mathcal E$ is the maximal volume ellipsoid contained in $K\subset\mathbb R^n$.

---

*My thoughts:* I understand that if $\operatorname{vol}(\tilde K) = \operatorname{vol}(Q)$, then $\operatorname{vol}(\partial\tilde K) \le \operatorname{vol}(\partial Q)$, but I'm still unsure because what guarantee is there that $\operatorname{vol}(\tilde K) = \operatorname{vol}(Q)$ happens (i.e. we can find such an affine image $\tilde K$)?

---

**References:**
(a) Keith Ball, An Elementary Introduction to Modern Convex Geometry.
(b) Keith Ball (1991). Volume Ratios and a Reverse Isoperimetric Inequality. Journal of the London Mathematical Society, s2-44(2), 351–359.

Comment: Here you see the difference between \text{} and \operatorname{}
$$
\begin{align}
& 2n\operatorname{vol}(\overline K) \\ {} \\
& 2n\text{vol}(\overline K)
\end{align}
$$
It's not just addition of a bit of horizontal space; rather the spacing depends on the context, thus:
$$
\begin{align}
& \operatorname{vol}(K) \\ {} \\
& \operatorname{vol}K
\end{align}
$$
(I edited this question accordingly.) $\qquad$

Comment: I did not try this yet, but I get the feeling I'll be able to clarify this. I'm sorry for the extremely delayed response, since non-MSE work has been on my head for some time this week. I'll give it a good go.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon No problem. It's been a while, so just dropping a reminder.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor On page numbers 36 and 37, a volume-ratio estimate is proved using the Brascamp-Lieb  inequality(which isn't proved, because it's quite hard). That VR estimate is applied to $K \subset C$ where $C$ is defined using John's theorem at the top of page 34. That proves that if $K$ has $B^2_n$ as maximal ellipsoid then $vol(K) \leq 2^n$. Now, the symmetric version of Thm. 6.1. is that if $K$ is a symmetric convex body and $T$ is the (unit) cube in $\mathbb R^n$, then there is an affine image of $K$ with volume $2^n$ but surface area greater than the unit cube. Continued...

Comment: The point is that the surface area of the cube is $\frac 1{2n}$ times the volume of the cube, so what the explanation  in the middle of page 33 proves, is that if $vol(K)$ equals the volume of the cube for any symmetric convex body $K$, then the surface area of $K$ is less than that of the cube, because it's less than $\frac 1{2n}$ times $vol(K)$, which is equal to the volume of the cube by assumption. Thus, theorem 6.1 is proved by the explanation. I didn't post this as an answer because I wasn't a 100% sure (but I am 99% sure!), but we can discuss this and make sure that it is the case.